# What are the steps to collect Overleaf projects in a offline mode with code errors?

Tags: errors, overleaf, offline

What are the steps to collect Overleaf projects in offline mode with code errors? like the Overleaf compiler, which ignores errors.

Comment: overleaf is a standard texlive it does not ignore errors they are logged as usual, if you download the project you can run exactly the same settings using latexmk if you wish.

Comment: just use the main `Menu` at the top and select `download source` to get a zip file you can use offline with a local tex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)*

In general, you can download the full project via the top **Menu** -> **Download** -> **Source**.

Note that it's not exactly possible to download the list of errors itself, but it is possible to download the log and other output files by clicking on the **"document"** icon next to **Recompile** and then scrolling down for **Other logs and Files** -> **output.log**. However, note that this wouldn't catch things like bibliography errors etc.

Also, as for Overleaf ignoring errors: It's not as simple. We indeed use the "nonstopmode" which will try to run through errors to deliver a PDF in as many cases as possible, but you still shouldn't ingore the errors. They are reported by a **red notification balloon** next to the **Recompile** button and tackling the errors is important, otherwise the PDF can contain quite some nonsense.